# Desktop folder and files disappeared

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity

I restarted my computer, and when I logged back in to my user, I noticed that all of my files that were on the desktop are gone. Instead, icons of all of my home folder are showed on my Desktop gui.

I opened the terminal and found out that there is no ~/Desktop folder!

What happened?! What do I need to do to prevent these icons from being seen on my desktop? Can I get the files that I had on my desktop back? Does anyone had a similar problem?

12.04 / wubi install, 32 bit.